# Clearing memcache AppEngine not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, memcached

I use the memcache session handling in AppEngine. Sometimes when doing releases I change objects in a way that renders memcache contents obsolete. When I do and Im testing I want to be able to clear my session.

Ive added a servlet to clear memcache that uses:

```
        try {
            CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheManager.getInstance()
                    .getCacheFactory();
            cacheFactory.createCache(Collections.emptyMap()).clear();
            outputMessage(response, "CLEARED cache");
        } catch (CacheException e1) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "cache issue", e1);
            outputMessage(response, "cache issue!!!!!!!!");
        }
```

and I dump out the session contents using:

```
    Enumeration<String> e = request.getSession().getAttributeNames();

    outputMessage(response, "DUMPING SESSION..");

    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = e.nextElement();

        outputMessage(response, "Name:" + name + " value: "
                + request.getSession().getAttribute(name).toString());

    }
```

Doing a dump of session before and after a clear doesnt look any different.

Am I using this right?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "clearing out the session"? Memcache is distinct from sessions.

Comment: And how are you dumping values? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem, I usually append a version id to the key of the object stored in memcache. For example, instead of:

```
memcache.add('key', 'value')
```

I do:

```
version = '1'    
memcache.add(VERSION + '#key', 'value')
```

Later, if I want to invalidate all the data in memcache, I just change the version number (and the entries already stored in memcache will be automatically deleted when they expire).

Comment: You should be careful that your keys cannot overlap with the numbers you use for versions.  For example, if I look in memcache and see 2 keys, 17 and 117, it is difficult to tell if they are both for object 7, one from version 1 and one from version 11, or if they are for objects 7 and 17, both from version 1.

Comment: Yup, you're right, that's why I add a '#' between version and key - and make sure no key has the '#' character.

Comment: So you had issues clearing memcache too? or just a non issue because of this?

Comment: After using this trick of adding a prefix, I had no issues anymore.